# Unity Multiplayer connection error before connecting "ClientDisconnected due to error: Timeout"?

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking, multiplayer, unity-networking

Here I am making an Multiplayer(only 2 players) Game in Unity. Im using NetworkManager class. Here one player will enter by starting a host and the other player will enter as client by entering Server's IPAddress. 
My issue is I am starting a server and when i try to connect front client i m getting the following error.

```
ClientDisconnected due to error: Timeout
UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkIdentity:UNetStaticUpdate()
```

But the same code was working fine before 30mins but getting this error frequently. Please help I am Stuck here.  :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I Got the reason behind this. This problem is because of Unity servers, sometimes the Unity servers are busy it seems so the connection cannot be accomplished between the multiplayers.